# How to add saxon-dom 8.8 to my nexus server

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to add Saxdon-dom.jar (8.8) to my Nexus server. I am not using the Nexus Pro version. Is there a way to do this?

The dependency I need is here:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo/net/sf/saxon/saxon-dom/8.8/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new maven 2 proxy repository into the instance, set the remote url of the proxy to "https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo".

Then add this repository into the group repository you are using for your build.